# How to make material design lite drawer position dynamic?

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

Just started using material design lite to create a website. Good stuff.

I've managed to hack the header to stay fixed at the top of the page while scrolling:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header" >
            <header class="mdl-layout__header">
                <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
```

etc.. just like in the demo

**CSS**

```
body div header{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Now when I scroll, the header stays at the top of the page with all of its elements; no problem.

However, when I press the hamburger button to open the drawer, it only displays properly if the scroll is at the top of the page. If the page is scrolled anywhere lower, part of the drawer is hidden.

Any idea how to solve this?

Note that I couldn't figure out a better way to keep the header at the top, so it could be that that is the real issue (i.e. the `position: fixed;` part)

Comment: Do you have any link to show this problem? Any working example of this issue would be good..

Comment: I ended up using materialize CSS instead of material design lite; the former is better documented and has more tutorials online. Thanks anyway